# Как ввести в одной строке n переменных

Tags: python

python как ввести в одной строке n переменных ( n вводится ранее )

```
n = int( input() )
```

а далее нужно в строке ввести n переменных.

Comment: Ввести - вы имеете ввиду через аргументы командной строки? `import os\n os.argv[0...n]`

Comment: Hellsher, любой ввод

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете ввести любое количество переменных в массив:

```
>>> arr = input().split()
1 2 3 4 5
>>> arr
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Заметьте, что это массив строк. Если нужно ввести массив целых чисел, то используйте следующую конструкцию:

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Comment: А если при вводе предпоследнего ошибка, то мы всё завалим и не оставим ничего во-второй конструкции.