# Как реализовать ввод двух чисел в одну строку через запятую?

Tags: python

нужно ввести два числа `0,0`
как сделать такой строчный ввод через запятую ,причем чтобы в каждую переменную записывалось соответствующее число?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как ввести в одной строке n переменных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1080042/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-n-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Comment: @Sadykhzadeh скажите , в чем интересно дубликат? мне нужно просто реализовать ввод в строку двух переменных через ЗАПЯТУЮ, а то что предложили Вы, там просто вводе определенного кол-ва переменных ,зависящих от введенного числа(кол-ва раз)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a, b = map(int, input().split(","))

print(a, b)
```

если чисел не ограничено, то можно их писать в список:

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split(','))
```

вместо `map` можно использовать `for`, но код будет подлиннее:

```
arr = [int(i) for i in input().split(',')]
```

Comment: а как это можно сделать без map?

Comment: @марат, привел код через `for`